# Twisted and Autobahn Pub/Sub; Listen on secondary port for messages

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn

I've studied Twisted a little bit and got the hang of Protocols and Factories and Defereds. I want to have a server that will on one had handle a Pub/Sub over websockets and on the other hand be able to receive the messages that it will publish at another tcp port.

The Autobahn examples show how you make a Router and Sessions and Components but I wasn't able to find a good explanation of how these work and what their meaning is and I don't see how I can pair this Autobahn classes with a twisted factory so that I can pass the received tcp message to the Autobahn class for publishing.

Can anyone offer some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/wamp/wamplet/wampirc/wampirc/client.py#L47) is an example that bridges IRC to WAMP (PubSub).

Essentially, in your TCP-whatever protocol, you need to have a reference to a WAMP session instance, and use that to bridge to WAMP.

The latter example is for WAMP v2 (the "new" thing). There are more examples for WAMP v1 - which you can look at (since the principles are the same):

- [Bridging Dbus to WAMP](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp1/apps/dbus)
- [Bridging Serial to WAMP](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp1/apps/serial2ws)